# Android Run another application while task lock

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, kiosk-mode

I set my application as a device owner and the screen is pinning when i call `startLockTask()` . my problem now when i try to run another application by using this method :

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.test");
startActivityForResult(i,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

(nothing happen)
what i have to do to make it run?

Edit : i tried adding

```
 dpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[] { getPackageName() ,"com.example.test"});
```

its not launching too.

Comment: What are you trying to do? app kiosk? (limit a device to use only specific apps?)

Comment: Can you describe step by step what you're trying to do and how you're doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the app with an `applicationId` is installed on the device. for example in your case the *applicationId* is `com.example.test`.
If the app was not installed, you can bring user to a market or let them choose an app.

```
String packageName = "com.example.test";
.
.
.
Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if (i == null) {
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
    // Open app in google play store: 
    // i.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName));
}
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi @Misagh, Can you able to solve related to like this issue which i'm facing 

Link->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190997/open-other-application-in-startlocktask-mode-using-setlocktaskpackages-string

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A DPC must whitelist apps before they can be used in lock task mode. Call `DevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages()` to whitelist apps for lock task mode as shown in the following sample:

```
// Whitelist two apps.

private static final String KIOSK_PACKAGE = "com.example.kiosk";

private static final String PLAYER_PACKAGE = "com.example.player";

private static final String[] APP_PACKAGES = {KIOSK_PACKAGE, PLAYER_PACKAGE};
// ...

Context context = getContext();

DevicePolicyManager dpm =
    (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName adminName = getComponentName(context);
dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminName, APP_PACKAGES);
```

you can declare in your app manifest file how an activity should behave when the system is running in lock task mode. To have the system automatically run your activity in lock task mode, set the `android:lockTaskMode` attribute to `if_whitelisted`

```
android:lockTaskMode="if_whitelisted">
```

taken from https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode#java

Answer (score 0):

Just try with startActivity when you are launching the app with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.test");
startActivity(i);
```

We shouldn't use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with startActivityForResult in lock task mode.