# Open other application in startLockTask mode using setLockTaskPackages() string array params in Android 5.0 (Lollipop) is not working

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, kiosk, kiosk-mode, android-screen-pinning

**Motive:** Building a KIOSK App for 5.0 & 6.0+ devices

**Method followed:** adb to run the “dpm set-device-owner” command.

By using `startLockTask();` my app entered into authorised pin mode successfully.

I had other challenge which is, I have to open other of my installed application from KIOSK app. I achieved this by constructing array of string packages and set it to DPM's `setLockTaskPackages`  below is the code sample

```
mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(mAdminComponentName, getKioskApps());

private String[] getKioskApps() {
    return (new String[]{getPackageName(),
            "com.test.sampleappone",
            "com.test.sampleapptwo"});
}
```

with this above code on `6.0 +` devices I can able to navigate **sampleAppOne** `(com.test.sampleappone)` & **sampleAppTwo** `(com.test.sampleapptwo)` successfully which is installed in my device & below is the navigation code.

```
private void openSampleAppOne() {

        Intent intentInv = new Intent();
        intentInv.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.test.sampleappone", "com.test.sampleappone.MainActivity"));
        intentInv.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intentInv);
}
```

the above code is working perfect in `6.0 (marshmallow) & 7.0 (Nougat)` devices but not in `5.0 (lollipop)`  device, which is my challenge now to do.

as per the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setLockTaskPackages(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String[])) `setLockTaskPackages` will be support from **API level 21** which is lollipop 5.0 but I don't know what I missed here to make the code work in 5.0.

**Thanks for the time & help to solve this problem.**

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933021/android-run-another-application-while-task-lock

Comment: @Ankita No luck with the answer referred from the link, thanks for the help.